# IOS sending post method data can access in php as get method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am very new to iOS. I am trying to send data through post method to PHP. In PHP it can't take data like `$_POST['data']`, but it takes `$_GET['data']`. My iOS code is as follows.

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/app_respond_to_job?emp_id=%@&job_code=%@&status=Worker-Accepted&comment=%@",SaveID2,txtJobcode1,alertTextField.text];

NSURL *apiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:apiURL];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

_receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

[connection start];
NSLog(@"URL---%@",strURL);
```

Can someone explain why is that, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Download this file https://www.dropbox.com/s/tggf5rru7l3n53m/AFNetworking.zip?dl=0

And import file in your project
Define in #import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Url"]];
   NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"emp_id":SaveID2,@"job_code":txtJobcode1.text,@"status":alertTextField.text};

   AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"rest.of.url" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

   } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


      NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
      manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
      [responseObject valueForKey: @"data"];



   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

      NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
   }];
   [op start];
```

Answer (score 0):

because you send your data via query string in url
i think it will work if you try to pass data in your request's body:`[urlRequest setHTTPBody:...]`

Answer (score 0):

POST parameters come from the request body, not from the URL string.  You'll need to:

- Call `setHTTPBody` on the request and provide the URL-encoded string (sans question mark, IIRC) as the body data
- Call `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` to set the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- Either remove the call to `[connection start]` or use `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` so that you aren't starting the connection twice.

That last one is kind of important.  You can get strange results if you try to start a connection twice.  :-)